# find data in another workbook range return type mismatch error n.13

Tags: vba

I have a problem with the following sub:

```
Sub prova()

Dim E As String

'Dim H As Range

'Dim G As String

E = range("D3").Value

range("F2").Select

'Set H = Worksheets("Sheet1").range("F3:F100")

range("F3:F100").find(What:=E, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

End Sub
```

It returns a type mismatch error.
The problem is related to the range where I want to search the variable E, either if I specify the range or I set it with a name (`H`).
If I replace `range(.....)` with `columns(6)` or with `cells` (it searches in all the spreadsheet) it works.
If I specify a range it doesn't work. I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of problems there -

First, the After: parameter expects a Range, and the default property of ActiveCell is .Value, thus your type mismatch.

Second, the After: parameter *must be in the Range* that .Find is called on. After you call `Range("F2").Select`, F2 is the active cell - this would give you a 1004 error.

I think you're looking for something more like this:

```
Sub prova()

    Dim E As Variant

    E = Range("D3").Value
    Range("F3:F100").Find(What:=E, After:=Range("F3"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, _
                          SearchFormat:=False).Activate

End Sub
```

You can find the expected parameters of the .Find method [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff839746.aspx).